# Why mercury has low temperature coefficient of resistance?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electric-current

Why is the temperature coefficient of resistance of mercury (metal) approximately zero? Its temperature coefficient of resistance should be much larger than, for example, [constantan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constantan) (alloy) due to larger no  of free electrons in it ?

Mercury = 0.000091

Constanton =0.000001

Comment: You should correct the values and add units to the temperature coefficients.

Answer (score 1):

Your temperature coefficients are wrong by [orders of magnitude](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electrical_resistivity_and_conductivity#Resistivity_and_conductivity_of_various_materials)!
The linear temperature coefficient of mercury at 20 degrees centigrade is $$\alpha=0.9·10^{-3}K^{-1}$$ and the one of constantan is $$\alpha= 0.8·10^{-5} K^{-1}$$ Thus the temperature coefficient of mercury is about 2 orders magnitude larger than the temperature coefficient of constantan. Constantan is an alloy of copper nickel made to minimize the temperature coefficient.